# Missunderstanding about ERC1155 for Game Dev

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-1155, games

After using ERC721 to develop some Collectable collections of NFTs, i'm trying to implement an ERC1155 smart contract to manage a game collection of elements.

### First, the needs

In a simplified version of the game I need:

- **Characters:** A collections of character, each one is unique and have their own metadata (Exactly what a ERC721 is able to do)
- **Coin:** Classic Fungible token, with an amount by address.
- **Cards:** Here is the trick. I have a collection of multiple cards (let's say 100 different cards), and every card have their own number of instance. (Example: 500 instances of each common card, and 10 instances of each legendary cards)

### The ERC1155 contract

If I understand well, I have at least one non-fungible token (characters) and one fungible token (coins), I have to implement the ERC1155 standards. (Even if I don't understand is my Card Collection is fungible (multiple instance of a single card) or non-fungible (cards have rarities))

Following [OpenZeppelin ERC1155 Documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155#constructing_an_erc1155_token_contract) I did this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155Holder.sol";

contract GameItems is ERC1155Holder {
    uint256 public constant CHARACTER = 0;
    uint256 public constant CARD = 1;
    uint256 public constant COIN = 2;

    constructor() public ERC1155("https://game.example/api/item/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, CHARACTER, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, CARD, 10**5, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, COIN, 10**18, "");
    }
}
```

### Questions

##### Mint on Constructor

Firs of all, I don't understand why do I need to mint all the items on the constructor ? I cannot let the users mint Characters and Cards by their own (like ERC721 contract) ? And instead of defining how many do I want, use a `maxSupply(uint256 tokenId)` function ?

##### Fungible / Non-Fungible ?

I really not understand how do this work. The documentation say (for this [the doc example](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155#constructing_an_erc1155_token_contract)):

> Note that for our Game Items, Gold is a fungible token whilst Thor’s Hammer is a non-fungible token as we minted only one.

So Token are defined Fungible and Non-Fungible if they are only one ? But.. How can it be unique ?

In my point of view, Characters can be minted an unlimited number of time (and probably coin too, but only from the game not from external). So do I have to removed those 2 lines ?

##### Cards: a Non-Fungible Collections of Fungible cards ?

It's starting to confuse me a lots..

**Multiple Collection?**

Do I have to define a Token ID for every card I have on the game ? Something like:

```
uint256 public constant CARD_A = 1;
uint256 public constant CARD_B = 2;
uint256 public constant CARD_C = 2;
/* [...] */
uint256 public constant CARD_ZZ = 100;
```

And them consider as collections of different token ? But I want them to be mint randomly.
Example, a user who will mint 5 cards, will receive 2 CARD_A + 2 CARD_H + 1 CARD_ZZ. This is the good way ?

**Cards are ERC721 like?**

If I predefined all the cards with their metadata (like a classic ERC721) I will be able to control them individually but identical cards (example 2 instances of CARD_A) will not be considered as Fungible (and regrouped on OpenSea for example)

### Conclusion

Sorry for the mess of this thread but I think I need for help to put things back in the right place..
I'm also looking for resources, tutorial, course, whatever quality i'm taking.

Thank everybody

Comment: Typically, posts with multiple questions aren't helpful to the community as a whole. Could you post each question as an individual post? Thank you.